# How to add all the python libraries in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

How can I add all the python libraries in Spyder IDE which I have already downloaded using Terminal and are present in the directory /home/{username}/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer, Just go to Tools -> PYTHONPATH Manager and add a path to these libraries and restart Spyder.